# Xamarin Android (Forms) Image capture dimensions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a surface view (a native view) in the android forms XAML like this

```
        <ContentView x:Name="SurfaceView" WidthRequest="1080" HeightRequest="1920">
            <androidViews:SurfaceView x:Arguments="{x:Static androidLocal:MainActivity.Instance}" />
        </ContentView>
```

for preview.

I am using a `ImageReader` for getting the captured result, its dimensions are set to 1080x1920.

In the `OnImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)` callback the dimensions are correct, however when I get the `byte[]`, save it, move the jpeg to a computer and look at the details, it is only 960x1280... Why ?

After desperate attempts at getting the correct size I said 'whatever' and set the `ImageReader` size to 10 times the original (10800x19200)
and what do you know... it now produces the 'correct' image size (1080x1920)
again... why?

Thanks

E1:Still active and looking for info as to why is it happening

Comment: could you show  some code like how to deal with image

Comment: @LeoZhu All I do with the image is take the ByteBuffer convert it into a C# byte[] and save it. No modifications are done. (if that is what you meant)